# How to throw an exception from a recursive function in scala that returns Int

Tags: scala, exception

I've recently started learning scala and as a part of an assignment, I need to write a function with following requirements: it has to be recursive and throw an exception in case of empty list. Tried this code, but the exception is always thrown.

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int =
  if (xs.isEmpty) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("empty list")
  } else {
    if (xs.head > max(xs.tail)) xs.head else max(xs.tail)
  }
}
```

**edited:** sorry for a mistake, of course the exception needs to be created with new. However, the function always fails with exception.
tried require(), but it returns a Unit type, hence the compiler says it cannot be put in there.
Is there a simple way of throwing an exception from a recursive function in scala whithout resolving to Try, Option and others?

Comment: You have to create a new exception to throw: `throw new NoSuchElementException`.  The problem has nothing to do with recursion or `Int`.

Comment: Psst, your recursion always ends in the empty case.  Might want to do something about that, since presumably you don't _always_ want to throw an exception.

Comment: Or you can look at `scala.util.Try`

Comment: Your could insert require(xs.length > 0, "empty list) as the first line of the function definition.  This would throw a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with message "requirement failed: empty array".

Comment: Try using a pattern match on various arrangements of list elements, it should make your base case clearer. For constructing recursive list operations, start from the smallest input possible and consider how it behaves as you add elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will always throw the exception because the recursion will always reduce to an empty list. My assumption is that you do not want to initiate any recursion if the list is empty. In that case, you can define an inner function to do the actual recursion.

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {

  if (xs.isEmpty) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("empty list")
  }

  def iter(xs: List[Int], currMax: Int): Int = {

      if(xs.isEmpty) {
        currMax
      }
      else {
        iter(xs.tail, if(xs.head > currMax) xs.head else currMax)
      }
  }

  iter(xs.tail, xs.head)
}
```

Note: the above is just an quick, dirty example that has not been tested completed. And stylistically, both examples would benefit with the use of pattern matching as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to `throw` a class. In Scala, just like in Java, you can only throw an instance of a class and not the class itself. You'd have to use one of [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)'s constructors

```
throw new NoSuchElementException("Tried to find the maximum element of an empty list")
```

Scala also allows you to avoid communicating failures by means of exceptions by providing an OOTB [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) type. But if your assignment requires you to use an exception, so be it.

Comment: How do you consider `IllegalArgumentException` _more_ meaningful than `NoSuchElementException`?  The reason why the argument is illegal is because there is no element in it!

Comment: @RexKerr the way I understand the docs, `NoSuchElementException` is supposed to be used in a very specific context. To indicate that you failed to check for the presence of an element in an `Enumeration` before fetching the next element. `IllegalArgumentException` is more general and its use in this context is more consistent with its documentation than in case of `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: yeah, the Scala standard library uses `NoSuchElementException` in plenty of places where `Enumeration` is not involved.

Comment: @SethTisue, @mucaho, fair enough. Removed the bit about `IllegalArgumentException`